# Submit trial version of application on azure marketplace

Tags: azure, iaas, azure-marketplace

I would like to submit an offering to the Azure Marketplace but I want the offering to be a trial version only. So, the user will have access to it for a certain period only and it will be free.
The offering I want to submit is a VM offering and right now I have an image of the VM ready.
I did not find much information on how can I achieve this or whether it is possible to only submit the trial version on Azure marketplace.

Comment: If my answer helpful please mark it as answer by clicking beside the checkbox of your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a trial version VM offer, please set **License Model** as "**Usage-based monthly billed SKU**" in SKU tab when you create offer. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal/virtual-machine/cpp-skus-tab. 
[image]

Comment: In this case I don't need to also provide the full version when the trial ends, correct?

Comment: @anonuser1, could you tell me what is "full version"?

Comment: The trial version is the application with certain features missing, while the full version is the actual application with all the features.

Comment: NO, you cannot do that.  When the trial ends, if your customer wants to continue to use your software, he needs to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

The Marketplace publishing guide is designed to help new and existing publishers learn how to use storefronts in the [Azure Marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us) and [Microsoft AppSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/marketplace-publishers-guide) to grow their business in partnership with Microsoft by listing applications and services.

> [Develop a Marketplace Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/gg312162(v=azure.100))

I would recommend you to reach out to the concerned team by logging a ticket using this link.[enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=48734891-ee9a-5d77-bf29-82bf8d8111ff)

Additional information:
Please visit this link to learn more about the Microsoft Azure Certified program and how to publish and sell your applications and services in the Azure Marketplace.:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/programs/certified/
For more information, check this:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/faq/